# What causes extra vertical space around caption with threeparttable and how to remove it?

Tags: threeparttable, vertical-spacing

I just noticed that Donald Arseneau's excellent `threeparttable` package adds extra vertical space before and after the caption. This can be seen in the MWE below where I have set `\abovecaptionskip` and `\belowcaptionskip` to zero to emphasize the added space.

Could you please help me figure out where the added vertical space comes from and how to remove it? I have tried to decipher the package code but it is sadly beyond my skill level.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{0pt}
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[h]
    \caption{Testing testing testing}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XXXX}
      A1 & B1 & C1 & D1 \\
      A2 & B2 & C2 & D2 \\
      A3 & B3 & C3 & D3 \\
    \end{tabularx}
  \end{table}

  \clearpage
  \begin{table}[h]
    % \vskip-\lastskip%\vspace{-.2\baselineskip}
    \begin{threeparttable}
      \caption{Testing testing testing}
      \vskip-\lastskip%\vspace{-.2\baselineskip}
      \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XXXX}
        A1 & B1 & C1 & D1 \\
        A2 & B2 & C2 & D2 \\
        A3 & B3 & C3 & D3 \\
      \end{tabularx}
    \end{threeparttable}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Animated MWE to show added space]

Comment: I have also posted a [question about a seemingly identical problem in Beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/603124/beamer-why-is-spacing-around-caption-different-with-without-threeparttable)

Answer (score 2):

As workaround can be use of the `caption` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx, threeparttable}
\usepackage[skip=0ex]{caption} %you can select desired value

\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[ht]
    \caption{Testing testing testing}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XXXX}
    \hline
      A1 & B1 & C1 & D1 \\
      A2 & B2 & C2 & D2 \\
      A3 & B3 & C3 & D3 \\
    \end{tabularx}
  \end{table}

   \begin{table}[ht]
    \begin{threeparttable}
      \caption{Testing testing testing}
      \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XXXX}
       \hline
        A1 & B1 & C1 & D1 \\
        A2 & B2 & C2 & D2 \\
        A3 & B3 & C3 & D3 \\
      \end{tabularx}
    \end{threeparttable}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice workaround! Still, that leaves the question of **why** it happens :-/ Btw, I posted a [question about a seemingly identical problem in Beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/603124/beamer-why-is-spacing-around-caption-different-with-without-threeparttable), but where your workaround confusingly does **not** work

Comment: @FredrikP, beamer has own caption facility which doesn't work well with `caption` package. Also `threeparttable` redefine caption style (that it is not wider than table), however this modification can be controlled by `caption` package, where you can use it.

Answer (score 1):

A fix without additional packages: put the caption after `\begin{table}`.

It works for beamer too. (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/603137/161015)

[image: x]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h]
        \caption{Testing testing testing}
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XXXX}
            A1 & B1 & C1 & D1 \\
            A2 & B2 & C2 & D2 \\
            A3 & B3 & C3 & D3 \\
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
    
    \clearpage
    \begin{table}[h]
        \caption{Testing testing testing}% put the caption here <<<
        \begin{threeparttable}  
            \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XXXX}
                A1 & B1 & C1 & D1 \\
                A2 & B2 & C2 & D2 \\
                A3 & B3 & C3 & D3 \\
            \end{tabularx}
        \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In this case you lost caption style features provided by `threeparttable` (caption can be wider than table), what is beside table notes main reason for use `threeparttable`.

Comment: @Zarko   The OP only  asked about the added space.  The MWE does not use any particular features of `threeparttable`. The fix is only one part of the question. My answer shows where it  comes from. Useful here and with beamer.

Comment: @SimonDispa It is indeed useful here, when the tabular is `\linewidth` wide. But that was perhaps a mistake. Ideally, I would like to use `threeparttable`'s capabilities to capture the width of the table and enforce that on the caption and the table notes.

Comment: @ Thank you for your feedback. Perhaps you could help the helpers with a more complete MWE using the features important to you.