# Beamer: why is spacing around caption different with/without threeparttable?

Tags: beamer, captions, threeparttable, vertical-spacing

What causes the inconsistent spacing around captions with and without `threeparttable` in Beamer? What causes this? And can it be fixed?

I recently posted [a question about the same issue in the article class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/602903/71332), but the [workaround suggested there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/602914/71332) doesn't seem to work with Beamer.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{threeparttable,tabularx}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{Only \texttt{table}}
    \begin{table}
      \caption{A table caption}
      \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XXXX}
        A1 & B1 & C1 & D1 \\
        A2 & B2 & C2 & D2 \\
        A3 & B3 & C3 & D3 \\
      \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
  \end{frame}

  \begin{frame}{Both \texttt{table} and \texttt{threeparttable}}
    \begin{table}
      \begin{threeparttable}
        \caption{A table caption}
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XXXX}
          A1 & B1 & C1 & D1 \\
          A2 & B2 & C2 & D2 \\
          A3 & B3 & C3 & D3 \\
        \end{tabularx}
      \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Animated MWE to show inconsistency more clearly]

Answer (score 1):

The fix: put the caption after `\begin{table}`. The answer also works for the article class. See    https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/603136/161015

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{threeparttable} 
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Only \texttt{table}}
        \begin{table}
            \caption{A table caption}
            \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XXXX}
                A1 & B1 & C1 & D1 \\
                A2 & B2 & C2 & D2 \\
                A3 & B3 & C3 & D3 \\
            \end{tabularx}
        \end{table}
    \end{frame}
    
    \begin{frame}{Both \texttt{table} and \texttt{threeparttable}}
        \begin{table}
            \caption{A table caption} % put the caption here
            \begin{threeparttable}          
                \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XXXX}
                    A1 & B1 & C1 & D1 \\
                    A2 & B2 & C2 & D2 \\
                    A3 & B3 & C3 & D3 \\
                \end{tabularx}          
            \end{threeparttable}
        \end{table}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Useful workaround! But, ideally, I would like to understand how `threeparttable` messes up the spacing and to be able to fix **that** without the altering "frame" code.