# What is the vertical space between tabular and tablenotes environments with threeparttable?

Tags: tables, tabularx, threeparttable, vertical-spacing

What vertical space is inserted between tabular and tablenotes environments when we use the threeparttable package? I'm trying to build a `tablenotes` environment that looks similar to the one from `threeparttable` but without most of its bells and whistles to use in Beamer, which [doesn't really work with `threeparttable`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/603124/71332). Alas, I find it quite hard to disentangle the [source code to `threeparttable`](https://ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/threeparttable/threeparttable.sty).

The following MWE shows how the vertical spacing between the tabular and the notes is different when I use a `tablenotes` environment and when I use a simple `\raggedright` paragraph.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[para,flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[h]
    \begin{threeparttable}
      \caption{With \texttt{tablenotes} environment}
      \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}Xccc@{}}
        \toprule
        & A & B & C \\
        \midrule
        First row heading  & 123 & 456 & 789 \\
        Second row heading & 123 & 456 & 789 \\
        Third row heading  & 123 & 456 & 789 \\
        \bottomrule
      \end{tabularx}
      \begin{tablenotes}
        \emph{Note:} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
      \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
  \end{table}
  \clearpage
  \begin{table}[h]
    \begin{threeparttable}
      \caption{Without \texttt{tablenotes} environment}
      \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}Xccc@{}}
        \toprule
        & A & B & C \\
        \midrule
        First row heading  & 123 & 456 & 789 \\
        Second row heading & 123 & 456 & 789 \\
        Third row heading  & 123 & 456 & 789 \\
        \bottomrule
      \end{tabularx}
      \raggedright \emph{Note:} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod\par
    \end{threeparttable}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Animated output from MWE]

Comment: It seems to be introduced by a simple `\par`.

Comment: I can replicate the issue you've come across with `tabularx` and `tabular*` environments, but *not* with `tabular` environments. Maybe the issue isn't related to the `tablenotes` environment but, instead, to the way `tabularx` and `tabular*` are defined.

Comment: @Bernard And yet, inserting a `\par` before `\raggedright` doesn't change anything :-/

Comment: @Mico Nice spotted! I suspect that you're right---it doesn't come up using `tabulary` either. I'll have a look-see in the source to `tabularx` and see what I can make of it...

Comment: @Mico If I remove the `threeparttable` environment and just use my `\raggedright` line, then the vertical spacing is just as in the second table from the MWE irrespective of whether I use `tabularx`, `tabular*`, `tabular` or `tabulary`. So, the vertical space is introduced by `threeparttable` but the package seems to treat `tabularx` and `tabular*` environments differently than it does `tabular` and `tabulary` environments.

Comment: @FredrikP - With some luck, @DavidCarlisle -- TeX and LaTeX guru extraordinaire, second-most-prolific answer provider on this site, and creator/maintainer of the `tabularx` package -- will notice your query and take a very close look into how the `threeparttable`, `tabularx` and `tabular*` are interacting and how/why their interactions are slightly different from the ways the `tabular` and `threeparttable` environments interact.

Comment: @Mico I added the `tabularx` tag to further lure @DavidCarlisle to join me :-D

Answer (score 3):

You may try `talltblr` environment (added in version `2021M` on `2021-08-01`) with [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package . There is a `footsep` option for setting this vertical space:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}

With \texttt{talltblr} environment, default \texttt{footsep = 6pt}:

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{talltblr}[
  caption = {With \texttt{talltblr} environment},
  remark{Note} = {Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod},
]{@{}Xccc@{}}
    \toprule
    & A & B & C \\
    \midrule
    First row heading  & 123 & 456 & 789 \\
    Second row heading & 123 & 456 & 789 \\
    Third row heading  & 123 & 456 & 789 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{talltblr}
\end{table}

With \texttt{talltblr} environment, set \texttt{footsep = 0pt}:

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{talltblr}[
  caption = {With \texttt{talltblr} environment},
  remark{Note} = {Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod},
  footsep = 0pt,
]{@{}Xccc@{}}
    \toprule
    & A & B & C \\
    \midrule
    First row heading  & 123 & 456 & 789 \\
    Second row heading & 123 & 456 & 789 \\
    Third row heading  & 123 & 456 & 789 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{talltblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The same source code also works in `beamer` documents:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` has its own system of tabular notes. It's easy to set the vertical space before the tabular notes by putting a command `\vspace` in the content of the key `tabularnote`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,booktabs,enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{NiceTabular}
  [tabularnote = {\vspace{5pt}Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod}]
  {@{}Xccc@{}}
    \toprule
    & A & B & C \\
    \midrule
    First row heading  & 123\tabularnote{A note}& 456 & 789 \\
    Second row heading & 123\tabularnote{A second note}& 456 & 789 \\
    Third row heading  & 123 & 456 & 789 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

The main drawback of the package `nicematrix` is that the tabular created by `{NiceTabular}` can't be broken (as, for example, in `longtable` or `tabularray`).